# Cant sync triggers when deploying Azure Function via VS code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I used terraform to create my function app, and then in VS code I create the sample app that they generate for you.  When I try to deploy to vs code using the azure functions plugin I get the following output.

```
6:04:05 PM test-trigger: Starting deployment...
6:04:26 PM test-trigger: Creating zip package...
6:04:26 PM test-trigger: Zip package size: 297 kB
6:04:28 PM test-trigger: Fetching changes.
6:04:44 PM test-trigger: Updating submodules.
6:04:45 PM test-trigger: Preparing deployment for commit id 'b4a19304-f'.
6:04:45 PM test-trigger: Skipping build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
6:04:46 PM test-trigger: Skipping post build. Project type: Run-From-Zip
6:04:46 PM test-trigger: Triggering recycle (preview mode disabled).
6:04:46 PM test-trigger: Updating /home/data/SitePackages/packagename.txt with deployment 20220428010427.zip
6:04:46 PM test-trigger: Deployment successful.
6:05:07 PM test-trigger: Syncing triggers...
6:05:52 PM test-trigger: Syncing triggers (Attempt 2/6)...
6:06:03 PM test-trigger: Syncing triggers (Attempt 3/6)...
6:06:24 PM test-trigger: Syncing triggers (Attempt 4/6)...
6:07:05 PM test-trigger: Syncing triggers (Attempt 5/6)...
6:08:27 PM test-trigger: Syncing triggers (Attempt 6/6)...
6:08:29 PM: Error: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.
```

How can I get more info on what causes this in vs code?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Tried restarting app, creating new function, deleted trigger config from associated blob.... no dice. Can see the very brief error message in activity log, no clues as to whats causing it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it by reverting to python programming model v1 (as opposed to v2 - only available via API/CLI or VS Code extension)
Tried clearing associated storage/cache, restarted the app service, created a new instance using paid plan, new functions etc...
Certainly server side as the activity logs track the error, though no details.

Comment: I want to validate a part of this solution. I tried clearing the blob storage for this function app assuming that would reset whatever bad configuration may have led to this error. No success. The only solution was to delete the entire resource and start over. I suspect the bad config was due to a Python V2 bug that allows different functions within the same Function App to have the same name. This bugs out not only the sync triggers method and the server but also the Azure Portal GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure, the deployment went through, but the synctriggers is a different story. I'd recommend a few things to help isolate to make sure it isn't just vs code causing synctriggers to fail.

1. You should be able to see the synctriggers in your activity log in the portal
2. The management rest apis are used for mostly everything you see or do with resource management:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/sync-function-triggers
   I'd try running this command from the try it button in the above documentation and see what it returns.
3. Finally you should be able to try a har trace in the browser by refreshing the portal under the functions blade for your function app to see what is returned in the batch request under the network tab for the synctriggers command as well.

You can try any combination of these and it should give you an idea of the synctriggers issue, however it could be networking restrictions on the app, config issue. Hard to say for sure without more context of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue and this was caused due to the mismatch of the configuration variable AzureWebJobsStorage set in the function app with the access keys of the storage account. We were using blob trigger.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the remote app was using my local `AzureWebJobsStorage` config because of VSCode settings. When VSCode deploys, it offers to overwrite the remote settings with my storage setting. When I first deployed, I clicked to overwrite and than all subsequent deploys failed.

I adjusted the remote setting to use an Azure storage and deployed again **without** clicking to overwrite the remote config.

So make sure to **skip** this step (do **not** overwrite):

[image: VSCode overwrite AzureWebJobsStorage option]

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue, from my experience, is usually related to an issue with the "AzureWebJobsStorage".

1. No storage account.
2. Referencing the wrong storage account connection string
3. Referencing the wrong storage account connection string in KeyVault

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35632386)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and I fixed it by allowing all network traffic to access the storage account being deployed to. When it wasn't working I had it limited to my home pc IP.